# How to bring array values out of foreach loop?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have a foreach loop like this.

```
if ( is_object($res_two)) {
  if($res_two->num_rows() == 0) { 
    echo "No Records Found";}
  else if( $res_two->num_rows() > 0) {
    foreach ($res_two->result() as $row ) {
      echo $row->js_id."\t". $row->designation."\t".$row->full_name."\t".$row->location."\t".$row->graduated_in."\t";     
      $mail2 =  $row->email;      
      echo $mail2 ;

      ?>  <a href="<?php echo base_url("uploads/".$row->resume."")?>">Download Resume</a> <br/><br/>  <?php
    }
  }
}
?>
```

Now I want to extract $mail2 details. However echoing $mail2 out of the code giving only one value instead of an array(if foreach loop iterates, it should have multiple values?).

How to get the multiple values of $mail2 outside the code?

Comment: Just put them to array `$mails[] = $row->email`

Comment: Try this. Insted of: $mail2 =  $row->email; use: $mail2[] =  $row->email;. Now email2 is array and you can get all emails outside of foreach loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
if (is_object($res_two)) {
    if ($res_two->num_rows() == 0) {
        echo "No Records Found";
    } else if ($res_two->num_rows() > 0) {
        foreach ($res_two->result() as $row) {
            echo $row->js_id . "\t" . $row->designation . "\t" . $row->full_name . "\t" . $row->location . "\t" . $row->graduated_in . "\t";
            $mail2[] = $row->email;

            ?>  <a href="<?php echo base_url("uploads/" . $row->resume . "") ?>">Download Resume</a> <br/><br/>  <?php
        }
    }
}
print_r($mail2);
?>
```